# Why do we put MY_Model in the core folder?

Tags: codeigniter

In the video tutorials [here](http://codeigniter.tv/videos/cat/48) I can see that `MY_Model.php` is placed in the core directory of my CI application just like `MY_Controller.php` would be.

My issue is that CI does not load models from the core directory.  I have stepped through CI and found that CI is only checking the `application\models` folder for models, not the `core` folder (found on line 279 of CI 2.1.0 Loader.php file).  This makes it so I cannot access `MY_Model` directly using `$this->load->model('MY_Model')`, though I can extend it just fine.

This makes me wonder why we are putting `MY_Model.php` in the `core` folder.  Any model that is in `application\models` can be extended AND accessed directly, so why not put `MY_Model.php` there?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for making `MY_Model.php` is extending Core model. Its not supposed to load using `this->load->model('MY_Model')`. Its already autoloaded. The aim of `MY_model` is making common method, properties for all model inside `application/models` without hacking the Core files. And if you have extended Core Model, you should write your application models with extending `MY_Model` not the `CI_Model`.

Comment: You said "Its already autoloaded".  I don't think this is correct.  If `core\MY_Model.php` were autoloaded then I wouldn't have make all of my other models extend it because its functions would already be available.

Comment: @typoknigi mean CI looking for Core folder and autoincludin that Class, othwise you will not able to to extend MY_model.